# Update gnuplot dataset without files from c++

Tags: c++, gnuplot, pipe

I've got a program which will produce a load of data.  I would like to plot that data every second, so that I can monitor it's progress.  In the example below, I'm creating 10 graphs (one per second) with the 'a' loop, this works fine if I plot a function, rather than data points.

In the b-loop I want to create a new set of x-y data which is then plotted.  I can create the data, but I can't figure out how to pass it to gnuplot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>     // usleep
using namespace std;

int main(){
// Code for gnuplot pipe

FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w"); // open pipe to gnuplot
fprintf(pipe, "\n");

fprintf(pipe,"plot '-' using 1:2\n");  // so I want the first column to be x values, second column to be y

int b;
for (int a=0;a<10;a++) // 10 plots
{
    for (b=0;b<10;b++);  // 10 datapoints per plot
    {
        // this is the bit I can't get right:
        fprintf(pipe,"%d %d\n",a,b);    // passing x,y data pairs one at a time to gnuplot
    }
    fprintf(pipe,"e\n");    // finally, e
    fflush(pipe);   // flush the pipe to update the plot
    usleep(1000000);// wait a second before updating again
}

// Don't forget to close the pipe
fclose(pipe);
return 0;
}
```

Edit:  code below should work - 10 data points plotted once per second for 10 seconds:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>     // usleep
using namespace std;

int main(){
// Code for gnuplot pipe
FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");

// set axis ranges
fprintf(pipe,"set xrange [0:11]\n");
fprintf(pipe,"set yrange [0:11]\n");

int b;
for (int a=0;a<10;a++) // 10 plots
{
    fprintf(pipe,"plot '-' using 1:2 \n");  // so I want the first column to be x values, second column to be y
    for (b=0;b<10;b++)  // 10 datapoints per plot
    {
        fprintf(pipe, "%d %d \n",a,b);  // passing x,y data pairs one at a time to gnuplot
    }
    fprintf(pipe,"e \n");    // finally, e
    fflush(pipe);   // flush the pipe to update the plot
    usleep(1000000);// wait a second before updating again
}

// Don't forget to close the pipe
fclose(pipe);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you will need to bring the `plot` inside the loop, as in:

```
for (int a=0;a<10;a++) // 10 plots
{
    fprintf(pipe,"plot '-' using 1:2\n");  // so I want the first column to be x values, second column to be y
    for (b=100;b<110;b++)  // 10 datapoints per plot
    {
        // this is the bit I can't get right:
        fprintf(pipe,"%d, %d\n",(a+1)*b,(a+1)*b*b);  // passing x,y data pairs one at a time to gnuplot
//              fprintf(pipe, "%d %d\n",b,a);  // passing x,y data pairs one at a time to gnuplot
    }
    fprintf(pipe,"e\n");    // finally, e
    fflush(pipe);   // flush the pipe to update the plot
    usleep(1000000);// wait a second before updating again
}
```

Additionally you also might want to set `xrange` and `yrange` before you plot to see what really is going on:

```
FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w"); // open pipe to gnuplot
fprintf(pipe,"set xrange [0:1115]\n");
fprintf(pipe,"set yrange [0:122500]\n");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input.  I've made the above modifications, but something isn't right.  I get no plot window, and no output to the terminal.  It just sits there for 10s and then returns with no display. any further insights?

Comment: Which OS are you using? this work fine for me on Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnuplot 4.4

Comment: ah, I had to install gnuplot-x11 (I'm on Mint 16).  One mystery solved!  The code above just displays a single point on each iteration of the plot - I would like to show more than that, is it possible to do so?

Comment: @zotty, glad about that! essentially the plot window is redrawn each time and in each iteration of the loop your code just gives it one point to draw, that's why you just see one point each time.

Comment: thanks! Ok, going back to the terminal, if I enter gnuplot, and type "plot '-' using 1:2 with lines" it allows me to enter as many data pairs as I like, followed by "e", and I'll get a line graph.  That's what I thought I was reproducing above. The a-loop creates a new plot, then the b-loop should be creating 10 data points, exiting back to a-loop, where "e" is passed and the plot updated with 10 points?

Comment: @zotty, I see! don't have a working solution from the top of my head, but I'm quite sure you will need to use something like `replot` for that, so that the canvas is not redrawn.

Comment: Thanks again.  It's late here, so knocking it on the head for now - but I have a suspicion that I've done something funny with the b-loop. and it's only getting to the "fprintf(pipe,%d %d..." line 10 times instead of 100... I'll look again tomorrow.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just as I was closing down I saw it... that sneaky little semi-colon after the b-loop!!  Son-of-a-gun!!  Got rid of that and it worked. Full code provided above.  Thanks @Zahaib

Comment: @zotty, Good job! to be honest I think I learned from this question than I thought I knew.